# Need to get names of places in English in Google Place Autocomplete

Tags: google-places-autocomplete

We are using `Google Places Autocomplete` to fetch address of any location that the user enters. Now, if the user enters Phuket, then the address returned is in Thai language and not English.

I have tried setting language as English

I have tried these options

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=en">
</script>
```

I have also tried

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=en&region=GB">
</script>
```

Similarly for `en-AU`,`en-GP` and also `language=en&region=AU`.
But I still get the name in `Thai` language instead of `English`.

I want to see the names in `English` instead of `Thai`

Comment: Weird, by default it works in English for me, and when I put `language=th` then it becomes Thai, but with `language=en` again becomes English, using the example code from [here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). Maybe it is because whatever you are trying to get, what is the place you are trying to get? Maybe it has only Thai metadata? If the place has only Thai title, of course, there is no way to get English title in the autocomplete results. For example [this place](https://goo.gl/maps/GAwwPAopqzYvNyo27)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate the issue, using the sample code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ky8pd1q/2/), and I was able to get the formatted address of "**Phuket, Thailand**" which is in English:

See results below:

```
address_components: [
    {
        long_name: "Phuket",
        short_name: "จ.ภูเก็ต",
        types: [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        long_name: "Thailand",
        short_name: "TH",
        types: [
            "country",
            "political"
        ]
    }
],
formatted_address: "Phuket, Thailand",
place_id: "ChIJT1JixOIxUDARIbo9BoWayuk",
```

You can get either the `long_name` in address_components or the `formatted_address` which are in English.

[image: phuket thailand sample]

Hope this helps!